# Can't upload some photos to instagram by instabot

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, instagram

I can't upload photos some photos to Instagram using instabot.
Some pictures are uploaded fine and some are not. The ones I can't upload are the ones I edit using "Pillow". Here is my code and after than I'll show you what I tried.

My photo editing function that uses Pillow:

```
def make_square(im, min_size=1080, fill_color=(255, 255, 255)):
    #here getting the width and the height of the picture and after that adjusting it's size for it to fit on a 1080px picture perfectly
    width, height = im.size
    ratio = 1080 / width
    width = width + 0.00
    height = height + 0.00
    width = width * ratio
    height = height * ratio
    height = math.floor(height)
    width = math.floor(width)
    im = im.resize((width, height)) #resizing the picture to width 1080
    #here is some code i got online to create a white picture then paste my picture on top of it to make the picture square
    x, y = im.size
    size = max(min_size, x, y)
    new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (size, size), fill_color)
    new_im.paste(im, (int((size - x) / 2), int((size - y) / 2)))
    return new_im # returning the new image so that I can save and upload
```

Here is my other function to upload picture to instagram :

```
from instabot import Bot
def UPhoto(Image, Caption):
    bot = Bot()
    bot.login(username = "username", password="password")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    try:
        if bot.upload_photo(Image, caption=Caption):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False
```

when I run the upload photo I get this error:

FOUND: w:1080 h:1080 r:1.0
2020-09-12 16:00:53,680 - ERROR - Photo Upload failed with the following response: <Response [400]>
2020-09-12 16:00:53,682 - INFO - Photo 'Post.png' is not uploaded.
2020-09-12 16:00:53,683 - INFO - Total requests: 54

what I tried:

- I tried to send the photo to my phone using whatsapp and Post it to instagram using my phone and it worked
- I tried uploading photo to whatsapp then downloading it, it downloads as jpeg, then I tried Posting it to instagram and it worked
- I tried changing file extension and uploading it but that didn't work
- I tried upload the picture as it is without editing it using Pillow and it worked for some and others not depending if the photo dimensions are acceptable by instagram or not
- I tried copying picture and then Posting it but that didn't work
- I tried editting the same picture with scikit image but that didn't work too

Basically that's all I wish you could help, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!
Converted the Image to "JPEG" and everything worked out great.
using :

```
new_im = new_im.convert("RGB")
```

Comment: This works! Can you possibly give a brief explanation of why you did this and how you came to know of this solution? Any thing in the docs?

Comment: Sorry for 7 months late reply, but lucky you that was so painful I still remember everything. Basically documentation around that topic was impossible to find, I had to keep testing and analyzing for a bit more than a month till I found the solution. Because I knew that when I uploaded the photo to a website and downloaded it again as a JPEG it did upload to Instagram normally, after that my main goal was to convert it to JPEG. I tested many many other ridiculous things but what I stated here is what actually got me closer to the solution.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! You saved me at least 7 months as well! I first tried simply editing the file extention to .jpeg, but that didn't work. Saving it as .jpeg worked like a charm!