# Cant post with Instabot

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I made a script to post the images that I made using Python, and post it on Instagram with instabot but when a play the script it gives me this error [403]:

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()

USERNAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"

bot.login(username = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD, use_cookie = False)

bot.upload_photo("post1.png", caption = "Test")
```

This is the error:

```
2023-01-27 20:03:56,718 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2023-01-27 20:03:56,718 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2023-01-27 20:04:01,268 - ERROR - Request returns 400 error!
2023-01-27 20:04:01,269 - INFO - Instagram's error message: challenge_required
2023-01-27 20:04:01,269 - INFO - Error type: checkpoint_challenge_required
FOUND: w:1080 h:1080 r:1.0
2023-01-27 20:04:02,791 - ERROR - Photo Upload failed with the following response: <Response [403]>
2023-01-27 20:04:02,792 - INFO - Photo 'post1.png' is not uploaded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already answered in this post: [Can't upload some photos to instagram by instabot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864611/cant-upload-some-photos-to-instagram-by-instabot)

All you need to do is convert you png file to jpeg.

By the way http response code 403, means that a client is forbidden from accessing a valid url. So, maybe your ip/account have been already blocked by Instagram.